# How to replace the export file with an MS-Access macro?

Tags: ms-access

I'm using MS-Access. My access has an AutoExec, and after all the queries execute, it has an action to export the two result tables (table_X and table_Y) in Excel format. However, I want to set this AutoExec to execute every day, and when I execute for the second time, a message pops up, saying that the files table_X and table_Y already exist in the directory.
How can I set the macro to replace old export tables with the new ones?

Comment: Post your code for analysis.

Comment: You could add code to your AutoExec to check for the files and delete them if present.